# Print PowerBi report that has long horizontol scroll bars

Tags: powerbi

I have a PowerBi report that is a table. This table is very long and can have 30+ columns which results in very long horizontol scroll bars in the table. When I try to print the report the full report isn't displayed as a result - does anyone know any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power BI is not designed to support this use case. It is intended to be an interactive reporting tool. For the type of reporting you want to do, you could look at paginated reports (SSRS) which is now supported in Power BI Premium, or you could use another reporting solution, like SSRS.